# delphi JvCreateProcess1: how to send keys

Tags: delphi

I run an invisible DOS process thanks to JvCreateProcess component; that works fine.
I need to stop this process by CTRL+C and not by JvCreateProcess1.terminate (or send CTRL+C sequence to JVCreateProcess)

Any idea ?
regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
GenerateConsoleCtrlEvent(CTRL_C_EVENT, myProcessInfo.dwProcessId);
```

but there are some limitations:

- You can only call GenerateConcolseCltrEvent from a process that **shares** its console with the process you are sending the Ctrl-C-Event to. If you need to catch the console output of the spawned process without it being intermingled with the console output of other spawned processes or the app spawning them, then you can't use this (directly, see below).
- The process receiving the Ctrl-C-Event in this way will/may **not** terminate any processes that it spawned itself. (Possibly dependent on the process group settings and console sharing amongst those processes, I didn't check further into this at the time when I was contemplating Ctrl-C'ing a spawned process.)

If you need to send Ctrl-C from an app that does not share its console with the spawned process you are left with creating an intermediate process that does and telling that to terminate by some other means (pipes, COM, whatever) so it can send a ctrl-c to the actual process that you want to spawn and terminate by Ctrl-C.

More info on this, and how to go about creating an intermediate process, can be found here: http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0698/win320698.aspx